# Disable emoji2 in textview in AppCompat 1.4.0 and later for performance purposes

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-appcompat

I updated my app dependencies from appcompat 1.3.1 to appcompat 1.4.1, where one of the key changes is:

> Updatable emoji support is enabled by default via the androidx.emoji2
> library

It seemed to me that the smoothness of RecyclerView in my app got worse, and Profiler confirmed this.
I have 4 TextViews in the ViewHolder whose setText method has always been one of the slowest actions in onBind.
But after the update, the situation has become disastrous:

onBind now takes 11ms on average, 7.3ms of which is summed up by `androidx.emoji2.viewsintegration.EmojiInputFilter.filter()` and `androidx.emoji2.viewshelper.EmojiTransformationMethod.getTransormation()` for 4 textview.
I don't need emoji support like most developers, I need the app to run smoothly. Is there any way to disable emoji2 without downgrading to 1.3.1?

Below is a screenshot from the profiler for one TextView.
The parent setText() method took 3.76ms.
Timing for filter() method provided in "Summary" tab (on the right) and in popup for getTransormation().

[image]

Comment: EmojiCompat also causes my app to crash on an internal argument check I can do nothing about (at no point in the stacktrace does execution reach my code), another good reason to disable it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer on emoji2 page: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/emoji2.
Paragraph "Configuring automatic initialization".

So to disable emoji2 we should add this code to <application> tag in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider
     android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
     android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
     android:exported="false"
     tools:node="merge">
     <meta-data android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer"
               tools:node="remove" />
 </provider>
```

The improvement in performance is obvious:
[image]
onBind now takes 6.5ms at all instead of 11ms.

Comment: In fact, the values from the profiler proved to be out of touch with reality.
Here are the great post: https://proandroiddev.com/can-you-trust-time-measurements-in-profiler-5b3566a55e0c, so probably emoji2 overhead very small.

Comment: Please check for other content providers. The mentioned one doesn't add too much overhead.

Comment: Hi @Umy I am a bit confused with your statement "so probably emoji2 overhead very small.", because it contradicts with your question, which mentions the performance problem is caused by emoji2. So, does emoji2 feature causes performance in your app?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `app:emojiCompatEnabled="false"` on your `TextView` if you don't want emoji support. I found it via https://youtu.be/QVj2tQm8r58?t=495 but I couldn't find any official documentation for this attribute.